# I can't copy pasted my words from a password manager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, copy-paste, textinput, react-hook-form

I'm working on a form in my react native project, using `react-native-paper` for the TextInput, `react-hook-form` and `yup` for the control of my fields.
I generate a string / password with a password manager like TrueKey with complex generation. The password in example look like this : `N8>){@W$7&H<+FOO`
I copy it in my clipboard and try to paste the string in my `TextInput` on my application.

Directly after pasted the string, the field in cleared and juste `N8>` stay in the field.

I tried to copy paste this string in Dashlane, another password manager, and when I paste it, it seems that there is some space between `N8>` and `)`, and between `)` and `{`.

First I wast thinking of react hook form when `onChange` or `onChangeText` is executed. But I completely remove this lib and used a simple `TextInput` from React native, but there is same problem.

I found this [URL](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18926), but the example used don't work for me. I tried to use `removeClippedSubviews={false}` on my ScrollView, or encapsulate `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` around my input.

I can reproduce the error just with that code :

```
<TextInput
    label="LabelOfMyField"
    style={EInput.basic}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
        doSomething()
    }}
/>
```

Someone has encountered that problem before ?